# Grunt no longer livereloads

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, bower

I'm new to web development and I'm trying to build a small webapp. I used yoeman to set everything up and it did pretty well, angular installed perfectly and I installed angular-animate and jquery-ui after with bower. Autoreloading the webpage happend automagically, I really liked it.

After a while it stoped livereloading my changes. I don't know why. I'm not sure what I did.

This is what my gruntfile watch section looks like:

```
    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
watch: {
  js: {
    files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
    tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
    options: {
      livereload: true
    }
  },
  jsTest: {
    files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
    tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
  },
  styles: {
    files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
    tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
  },
  gruntfile: {
    files: ['Gruntfile.js']
  },
  livereload: {
    options: {
      livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
    },
    files: [
      '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
      '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
      '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
    ]
  }
}
```

It looks ok right? No errors showing up when running:

```
grunt serve
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem where LiveReload would stop working after a while.

What worked for me was reinstalling the LiveReload Chrome Extension, so if you didn't make any changes to the Gruntfile you can try that.

Comment: Wich extension did you use? I tried "LiveReload" and it didn't work.

Comment: I used the "LiveReload" extension. Make sure you turn on the "Allow access to file URLs" option and also turn it on in Chrome. The icon looks like [this](http://www.blog.philiptutty.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Screen-shot-2013-05-21-at-4.02.16-PM.png)

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I'm using some drag and drop functionality, and that REALLY slows down using LiveReload. Thanks anyways. I started a new project and copy pasted my code and it started working again.